# Setting up C project in Xcode 11.x

Tags: c, xcode

I'm trying to set up a simple project that will contain c source code. I can't find anything via google for newer versions of Xcode.

Best I could figure out is to create a new command line project and then manually add in a C program file. Is this the only method?

Answer (score 0):

After selecting Command line app, hit next. Then be sure to select language type to "C" and then continue.